# Generate a URL From Route Data ONLY

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm trying to do something simple in ASP.NET MVC:

```
RouteValuesDictionary routeValues = GetMyRouteData();
var url = new UrlHelper(Html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
return url.RouteUrl(routeValues);
```

The problem is that no matter what I do, the url includes route data from the current request context. I want to generate a URL based on ONLY the route values from `GetMyRouteData()`.

Thanks

Comment: what context (controller?) is this code?

Comment: Just an observation: different routes may contain the same tokens, and map to the same controller action, so you may not get the url that you're looking for in any case (as they are not necessarily unique).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The problem is that no matter what I do, the url includes route data
>   from the current request context

That's by design. You have to explicitly set the route values that were present in the original request and that you don't want in the resulting url to null:

```
    var routeValues = GetMyRouteData();
    // remove values that you want to exclude from the resulting url
    // by setting their values to null
    routeValues["id"] = null;
    var url = new UrlHelper(Html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    return url.RouteUrl(routeValues);
```

Comment: @Paul, great, then you are doing it right. Is there something else you need to know?

Comment: Like in this example, the routeValues doesn't include ID (it's been removed) but since it's part of the current route it gets included in the returned URL.

Comment: @Paul, yes, that's perfectly normal. That's how url helpers such as `RouteUrl` are designed by the ASP.NET MVC team. So I repeat my question: is there something else you need to know?

Comment: Just...the original question! I get that it pulls the routing info from the current context, I'm looking at the MSDN doc that describes the order of precedence right now. That's why I asked the question, just looking for an easy way to get around it.

Comment: @Paul, the way to get around it is to remove the route values from the  RouteValueDictionary collection manually because otherwise the helper uses the original values from the request. I already answered your question: you have a couple of possibilities: write your own custom Url helper which behaves as you want and don't use the `RouteUrl` helper since that's how it is designed to, or remove the values you don't want from the argument you are passing to it. Is there something not clear about it? Seems pretty straightforward to it.

Comment: "Exclude the route values that were present in the original request and that you don't want in the resulting url manually" doesn't work. I'll post a solution here once I'm done.

Comment: @Paul, you need to set them to null: `routeValues["id"] = null;`? I have updated my answer.

Comment: Is there an implementation of GetMyRouteData() I'm not seeing?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov So I get everything you've said here - but do you know at all *why* it is designed this way?  I've got a scenario whereby I post a form to a url which also includes a parameter on the URL.  Using RouteUrl in code in the context of this request generates urls which also include this extra parameter.  I can't see a situation whereby that would ever be desired behaviour.

Comment: @Justin, it allow you client to cumulatively apply parameters without forcing you to build them yourself each time. So if you've got a link that adds a `?type=employee` query parameter, you can create another one that adds `&page=1` without having to think about what you're doing. USUALLY this is the correct behavior, and prevents a type of navigation error that tends to go undetected. (e.g. developer tests paging, but never has more than one page when employees filter is applied for example.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to ASP.NET MVC, but due to ASP.NET Routing's route resolution. The entry point to this is `RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath`, which has two signatures.

The first takes a `RequestContext` and a `RouteValueDictionary`. This is used for default route resolution, which relies on pattern matching to find a route. The route search incorporates all tokens from `RequestContext` as well as `RouteValueDictionary`; in other words, the two sets of route tokens are combined to form the basis for the route search. A special case exists whereby null parameters in the `RouteValueDictionary` remove that parameter from search. However, if such a null-valued parameter has a value in the `RequestContext`, that value will still appear in the generated URL as a query string value.

The other signature additionally accepts a route name. It is a little strange because it alters both the route resolution as well as the query string creation.  Routes are found, obviously, using name resolution.  Given the named route is found, only tokens for those  parameters specified in route's URL pattern will appear in the generated URL.

Why is it this way? It's ASP.NET MVC's interpretation of Ruby on Rails' parameter-handling convention.

So default route resolution and "fallback" token resolution are comingled. If you don't want tokens to fallback to the `RequestContext`, (and you still want to use ASP.NET Routing) you have to use named route resolution.

Answer (score 0):

This might help clarify.  Use the source, Luke!

The RouteUrl helper calls into this static method to generate the URL:

```
public static string GenerateUrl(string routeName, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, RouteCollection routeCollection, RequestContext requestContext, bool includeImplicitMvcValues) {
        if (routeCollection == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("routeCollection");
        }

        if (requestContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");
        }

        RouteValueDictionary mergedRouteValues = RouteValuesHelpers.MergeRouteValues(actionName, controllerName, requestContext.RouteData.Values, routeValues, includeImplicitMvcValues);

        VirtualPathData vpd = routeCollection.GetVirtualPathForArea(requestContext, routeName, mergedRouteValues);
        if (vpd == null) {
            return null;
        }

        string modifiedUrl = PathHelpers.GenerateClientUrl(requestContext.HttpContext, vpd.VirtualPath);
        return modifiedUrl;
}
```

Note the line:

```
RouteValueDictionary mergedRouteValues = RouteValuesHelpers.MergeRouteValues(actionName, controllerName, requestContext.RouteData.Values, routeValues, includeImplicitMvcValues);
```

This is merging in the current requestcontext values under the covers.  So, you could make your own helper that just calls into this static method and passes empty collections to avoid getting the current route context values being merged in.  Experiment and debug into the MVC code and you should be able to see which values you need to nuke.

Comment: RouteValuesHelpers.MergeRouteValues is marked internal, unfortunately.

Comment: Great.  Not sure if this was different in older MVC versions or if I just missed it.  The method is public, but the static class it hangs off is internal.  The source is open so you could pick out some pieces of code to do what you want if there is no public alternative.  BTW, the code being discussed for MergeRouteValues is in this file:  http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/504b0aa28c37#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fRouteValuesHelpers.cs

Comment: True.  The downside of copying their code into my codebase though is I don't have test coverage nor protection if things in ASP.NET MVC change in later versions.

Comment: This is **wrong**. The "merging" in `RouteValuesHelpers.MergeRouteValues` refers only to "required" values: "action", and "controller". The use of current request route values occurs in ASP.NET Routing's virtual path resolution, in a deeper call to `RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext, RouteValueDictionary)`.