# Asp.Net MVC localizing routes with default language

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, globalization

I need to provide language specific routes for my Asp.Net MVC application. The language should be part of the Url Path (http://myapp/en/Blog) and when it is ommitted the default language have to be used.

http://myapp/en/Blog -> Blog in the English version
http://myapp/Blog -> Blog in the Default (portuguese) Language version

To address this issue I created two Routes bellow:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default.lang",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { lang = @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}$" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The routes are working as expected but I'm getting weird results when I try to use the Url.RouteUrl method to get alternative language urls.

**Example 1 -** Path: /

```
url.Action("Index", "Blog") // returns "/Blog" that is OK
url.Action("Index", "Blog", new  { lang = "en" }); // returns "/en/Blog" that is also OK
```

**Example 2 -** Path: /en

```
url.Action("Index", "Home") // returns "/en/Blog" (??????????) Not OK
url.Action("Index", "Home", new  { lang = "en" }); // returns "/en/Blog" that is OK
```

As you can see I get a wrong result when I access the url http://myappurl/en and try to use the Url.Action method without pass any route value (same result with Url.RouteUrl)

Does anyone knows what is wrong with my routes?

**[EDIT]** I'm not sure if the issue is related to the route because I've tested the routes using "en" as first route's constraint and I got the same result.

Comment: I see the order of your `MapRoute` tends to execute `Default.lang` first rather than `Default` one. Try reversing the route by setting `Default` at top order and see what kind of routing will happens.

Comment: The constraint of the Default.lang route avoids that Default route be hidden. Reversing the order will hide the Default.lang route. Thank you @Tetsuya Yamamoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging inside System.Web.Mvc and System.Web.Routing source code I found that this behavior is expected. I presume that it is designed to correctly work in applications running inside Virtual Directories.

This can be confirmed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15370677/4738253) that I found when was researching if someone else had the same problem with virtual path and route resolution.

**Workaround**

Use named route resolution with Url.RouteUrl method that has and different implementation and works as expected.

**Example**:

```
var blogDefaultUrl = url.RouteUrl("Default", new {action = "Index", controller = "Blog"});
var blogLangageSpecifictUrl = url.RouteUrl("Default.lang", new { action = "Index", controller = "Blog", lang = language });
```

I was avoiding to use named routes because my application design is a little bit more complicated than I demonstrated above. By this reason I have to discover at run time the route that matches the Request.Url and from that point I call the RouteUrl to get the alternative languages url to the content.